# Select FullName and add-content to File

Tags: powershell

I've got the following powershell line:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem  -Path "C:\temp" -Filter "*ä*" -Recurse | Select FullName
```

I want to write those paths to a *.txt file:

```
foreach ($item in $items){   
   add-content -Path C:\temp\test.txt -Value $item -Force
}
```

Output in test.txt:

> @{FullName=C:\temp\ä}

How can I only write the Value of FullName to the txt-file ? 
For example:

```
echo $item
```

and Output in Console:

> C:\temp\ä

Comment: `write-host $item.FullName`?

Comment: Didn't thought it would be that easy, thx!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Common gotcha with PowerShell. `$items` is not an array of FullNames but an object array with a fullname property. (Array assuming more that one item was returned.)

```psh
$items = Get-ChildItem  -Path "C:\temp" -Filter "*ä*" -Recurse | Select -Expand FullName
```

or

```psh
# Requires PowerShell v3.0 or above
$items = (Get-ChildItem  -Path "C:\temp" -Filter "*ä*" -Recurse).Fullname
```

Comment: Both examples are working fine. Second one should be .FullName not .Fullname. Thx for your help!

Comment: @Matt The second syntax will only work in PS3 or above, please make a note. There was a question yesterday about why that syntax doesn't work, the answer was "too low PS version".

Comment: @SaintCore the case would be a cosmetic difference and would work either way as properties are not case sensitive.

Comment: @Vesper yes that is true but man 3.0 has been forever now... but yeah not everyone has it.

Comment: i wish i could have found this 3 hours ago

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
foreach ($item in $items){   
   add-content -Path C:\temp\test.txt -Value $item.FullName -Force
}
```

Here's a common way to find this bit of info:

```
Get-ChildItem | Get-Member
```

Or the same with shorthands:

```
dir | gm
```

This will list all properties, methods, etc for the objects returned from `Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: As I said in my comment above your solution is working for me, but I think Matts solution is " more common" because of getting rid of it already while filtering.